# Using if and else to decide different user's login activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have this code it works fine  before adding the last else for this  selected users 
when I  add else, it ignores the first if(ocmt@yahoo) and second if (ocmt1@yahoo.com) and goes directly to else 
I want to add else direct to any other user to different  default activity

```
if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
    // there was an error
                                if (password.length() < 6) {
                                    inputPassword.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            } else {
                                 if(inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("ocmt@yahoo.com") ) {

                                     Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
                                     startActivity(i);
                                 }
                                if(inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("ocmt1@yahoo.com") ) {

                                    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, List2Activity.class);
                                    startActivity(i);
                                }
                         else{
                               Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, List3Activity.class);
                                    startActivity(i);
                            }

                            }
                        }
                    });

        }
    });


}

public void contasguest(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ImageListshopActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

code here

Answer (score 0):

You only forgive one `else if` next the if, the correct way:

```
if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
// there was an error
                            if (password.length() < 6) {
                                inputPassword.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } else {
                             if(inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("ocmt@yahoo.com") ) {

                                 Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
                                 startActivity(i);
                             }
                            else if(inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("ocmt1@yahoo.com") ) {

                                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, List2Activity.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                     else {
                           Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, List3Activity.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                        }

                        }
                    }
                });

    }
});
```

}